# Google Calendar Work Location Overview

Tags: google-calendar

Google Calendar offers a Work Location option to specify whether you're working at home, another remote location or at the office.

[image]

It would be nice to see an overview of all employees that work at the office and that work remotely, based on these settings.
Does Google Calendar have such an overview?

Comment: What type of account are you using? Be specific (Business Starter, Enterprise). Also mention if you are a super admin.